# Android Cursor - Concatenate/Append a String

Tags: android, mysql, bluetooth, android-sqlite

I want to append/concatenate a string so that i can use that string to print into a bluetooth printer.

//The cursor data is from sqlite database

//Here is my code snippet

```
Cursor cursor = db.db_getAll();
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String message = "Hello";
    do {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_NAME));
        message += " Name: "+name+" \n";
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    message += "Thank You! \n";
}
```

After this, I will print this message into a bluetooth printer. The printing is successful but it prints only...

```
Hello
Thank You!
```

PS: The cursor is working because Im also using it to save into mysql database from sqlite database.

I am thinking of using StringBuilder. Help pls? :D

Comment: I think cursor.moveToNext() is false. that's why returned message is like that. Please check cursor.moveToNext() first.

Comment: Like i said, the looping is OK. I am using this same loop to save data to mysql, and it works fine.

Comment: @Maki try to add a log inside your loop. If your log has an output, then the loop is working well and if its not then the problem is inside your loop. eg. `Log.i("Message", "Name: " + name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before do-while loop, use `cursor. moveToFirst()`

If you want to use `StringBuilder`, Use a `StringBuilder` object in place of your `message` variable which is `String` object and use `builder.append(str)` instead of `+=`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("Hello");
Cursor cursor = db.db_getAll();
cursor.moveToFirst();
do {
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_NAME));
    builder.append(" Name: ").append(name).append("\n");

} while(cursor.moveToNext());
builder.append("Thank You! \n");
String message = builder.toString();
```

Comment: This is what im trying to do. Can you please give a code snippet for this? Thanks

Comment: Hi, the loop is ok, and yes I have if(cursor.moveToFirst()) { do while statement}.